MAXScript 3ds Max: Connect All Vertices in Edit Poly Modifier
I'm trying to create a script (MAXScript) that will connect all the vertices (creating edges between them) in the Edit Poly modifier of a selected object.
I took as a basis another script that randomly moves vertices inside the Edit Poly modifier, but I just can’t manage to remake it to suit my task.
(
    local theMesh = selection[1]
    
    if selection.count == 1 then
    (
        if classof theMesh.modifiers[1] == Edit_Poly then
        (
            SetCommandPanelTaskMode #modify
            subObjectLevel = 1
            
            for vert in (theMesh.mesh.verts as bitarray) do
            (
                theMesh.modifiers[#Edit_Poly].Select #Vertex #{vert}
                theMesh.modifiers[#Edit_Poly].MoveSelection [(random -10 10),(random -10 10),(random -10 10)]
                theMesh.modifiers[#Edit_Poly].Select #Vertex #{}
                theMesh.modifiers[#Edit_Poly].Commit ()
            )
        )
    )
)

I would be grateful for any help with the script.
